# How is dictionary[@"key"] implemented in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, overriding

If we want to override `[dictionary objectForKey:@"key"]` it can be done by subclassing `NSDictionary` class. How to override `dictionary[@"key"]`? In this context I want to know how `dictionary[@"key"]` is implemented.

Thanks!

**Edit:** 
I wanted to find a scalable way to parse an API response while preventing `[NSNull null]` from crashing my app. I have written category for `NSDictionary`, but I wanted a way to parse in this syntax: `data[@"key"]` 
So, I was evaluating the feasibility of subclassing `NSDictionary`.

Comment: why a negative vote?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `dictionary[@"key"]` this gets converted into a call to `[dictionary objectForKeyedSubscript:@"key"]`.  `objectForKeyedSubscript:` has the same behaviour as `objectForKey:`.

If you want to change the behaviour of `dictionary[@"key"]` then you will need to override `objectForKeyedSubscript:`.

Apple's [NSDictionary API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdictionary/1415430-objectforkeyedsubscript?language=objc) has a little more information.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: This question is pretty old now, but it just recently came to my attention again, so I thought I would add an example of wrapping `NSDictionary` as I would recommend. This could be made more robust and feature rich, but it's an okay place to start.

```
@interface NilSafeDictionary: NSObject
   -(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;
@end

/** Category on NSDictionary to create a nil-safe wrapper. */
@interface NSDictionary <NilSafeConvenience>
  - (NilSafeDictionary*)nilSafe;
@end

@implementation NilSafeDictionary {
   NSDictionary* _internalDict;
}

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _internalDict = [dict copy];
  }
  return self;
}

- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id<NSCopying>)key {
  id obj = _internalDict[key];
  if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    return nil;
  }
  return obj;
}

@end

@implementation NSDictionary <NilSafeConvenience>
  - (NilSafeDictionary*)nilSafe {
    return [[NilSafeDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self];
  }
@end
```

> **CAVEAT**: You don't explain here what problem you're trying to solve, but for anyone who comes across this question in the future, subclassing `NSDictionary` is almost certainly **never** what you want.

NSDictionary is a class cluster. Class clusters are tricky to subclass correctly with guidance, plus Apple's documentation explicitly tells you **not** to subclass, so there's no guidance on how to do it correctly.

Even if you're able to use your subclass and have it "work correctly" for your purposes, every other piece of code in the system will still be returning the original `NSDictionary` class, not your subclass, so it doesn't benefit you.

If you're hell bent on modifying the way `NSDictionary` works, create your own wrapper class that has an `NSDictionary` inside and create your own `objectForKeyedSubscript:` implementation.

***Yes***, you can add subscript indexing to your own custom class just like `NSDictionary`!

Comment: @crypt: I guess this question is about a month old, but if you'd like to figure out a better way to solve your problem, please post some more info.

Comment: I want to parse server API response which may have null values for random parameters. I want to make my app crash safe under all such conditions. For that I have written category for NSNull which returns default values for common NSString and NSNumber methods. 
Also, written categories for NSArray and NSDictionary returning nil for null.

Answer (score 0):

`dictionary[@key]` is short hand for calling `[dictionary objectForKeyedSubscript:@"key"]`. Therefore to override the functionality of `dictionary[@"key"]` you can subclass `NSDictionary`.

```
@interface MyDictionary : NSDictionary
  - (id) objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key;
@end
@implementation MyDictionary
  - (id) objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key 
  { 
    /*
      ...
    */
  }
@end
```

---

*Original answer using categories, however this approach isn't advised as it will override the original method removing access to `super` and potential of clashes should multiple categories be loaded overriding the same method. The last category to be loaded will be used at runtime, therefore you cannot guarantee which that will be.*

`dictionary[@key]` is short hand for calling `[dictionary objectForKeyedSubscript:@"key"]`. Therefore to override the functionality of `dictionary[@"key"]` you would create a new category for `NSDictionary`.

```
//Category in NSDictionary+CustomKeyedSubscript.h and NSDictionary+CustomKeyedSubscript.m
@interface NSDictionary (CustomKeyedSubscript) 
  - (id) objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key;
@end
@implementation NSDictionary (CustomKeyedSubscript)
  - (id) objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key 
  { 
    /*
      ...
    */
  }
@end
```

Comment: But is it a good practice to override methods in category? AFAIK categories should be used only for adding new methods and not for overriding.

Apple says : "If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class, or a method in another category on the same class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime. This is less likely to be an issue if you’re using categories with your own classes, but can cause problems when using categories to add methods to standard Cocoa or Cocoa Touch classes."

Comment: No you're right, there's no guarantee your category override will be loaded last. It also removes the ability to call `super`, amended answer to use a subclass.